# Push notification getting mutiple times in android

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have created a mobile application by using Eclipse.

The server sends push notifications  via GCM (in Php).

Upon installation of the APK for the first time, it sends one push notification, which is working correctly. For the seconds time (same APP on the same device) it sends twice, and third time, three times and so on.

I have discovered the problem is caused by adding more IDs of same device. So if I manually delete all the IDs and install the APK again, it will work fine.

```
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$fields = array('registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,'data' => $message,); $headers = array( 'Authorization: key=' . 'asbjadbdb','Content-Type: application/json');        
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {  die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));}
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Android side

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification(false,"Send error: " + extras.toString(),null,null,null);
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification(false,"Deleted messages on server: "
                        + extras.toString(),null,null,null);
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {
//              sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server:\n\n"
//                      + extras.get(ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY));
                String name=extras.getString("name");
                String address=extras.getString("address");;

                sendNotification(true,name,address);

            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```

Comment: can you provide the code for sending and receiving notification?

Comment: Upon installation of the APK for the first time, it sends one push notification, which is working correctly. For the seconds time(same APP on the same device), it sends twice, and third time, three times and so on.

Comment: Ok, but help us help you by giving us the actual code you wrote to send the push notifications

Comment: @sharsadkk! show us the code first.

Comment: Write your Php code that overwrite the previous push id, it is same.

Comment: No please. place the code in the `Question` by editing it and remove your `API KEY` since it's **secret** and you **don't** want to share it with us.

Comment: How do you recover and store the `$registration_ids`? How to you handle the push in the Android App? Post also that code.. BTW i'm working on an answer that will cover the whole (server side) push management as I used it in my works

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/      ........ Help me

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to work with Push notification via GCM using PHP.

The server is a complex REST server but right now you need to understand only a few parts of it.

#### Receive and store a `Push token`

You need a `Push token` in order to identify on which device GCM should send the push. Hence you need to store it but keep in mind that it might change thus, if that happens, you application needs to send the new one to the server and it needs to be changed in your database.

#### Send the `Push notification`

To send a push notification I recover the `Push token` from database and then use the `PushSender` class to actually send the `push notification`

Retrieve `push token` with a query from my `MySql` server.

Usage of the `PushSender` class:

```
$push = new PushSender('The push title','The message',$push_token]);
$ret = $push->sendToAndroid();

// Check $ret value for errors or success
```

The `PushSender` class:

```
Class PushSender {

    private $title;
    private $message;
    private $pushtoken;

    private static $ANDROID_URL = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    private static $ANDROID_API_KEY = 'YOUR-API-KEY';

    public function __construct($title, $message, $pushtoken){

        $this->title = $title;
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->pushtoken = $pushtoken;
    }

    public function sendToAndroid(){

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => array($this->pushtoken),
            'data' => array( "title"=>$this->title, "message" => $this->message ),
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . self::$ANDROID_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::$ANDROID_URL);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , false );

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if( curl_errno($ch) ){
            curl_close($ch);
            return json_encode(array("status"=>"ko","payload"=>"Error: ".curl_error($ch)));
        }

        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

#### Receive the `push notification` in Android via a Service.

```
public class PushListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

        String message = data.getString("message");

        // Do whatever you need to do
        // Then send the notification
        sendNotification(message);
}

private void sendNotification(String message) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.an_icon)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(Helpers.getString(R.string.push_notification_message))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    try{
        notificationBuilder
                .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)getDrawable(R.drawable.your_icon)).getBitmap()));

    }catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: @sharsadkk do you need more explanation or examples?

Comment: am done like you explained above. But for the seconds time installation ,device getting 2 time notification

Comment: am sending each login time to phpMyAdmin . if token same not doing anything else add new entry to db

Comment: The code you posted that contacts `GCM` is nested in a loop or similar? How do you retrieve the pushtoken from db? have you tried printing it on your server before using it (try: `var_dump($registration_ids);`) to see if it contains only **one** push token (as it should) or if it contains a duplicated push token (which could lead to multiple sends)

Comment: using unique username with multiple device.so i cant identify which device token. always have above 1

Comment: Please, edit your question adding the code with the retrieval and set of the `$registration_ids` and add the output of the `var_dump`